# jQuery animation flips back

Tags: jquery, animation

For fun I tried to animate an object and load content after it, because I loved the idea.
It's working but theres a bug in the jQuery I guess, which I can't handle currently.
The Divbox 'nav' should animate to the top and STICK there! after that it should load the content. It's working but the nav box wont stick to the top in Firefox 4.0. In Firefox 3.5 there is no Animation! Firefox 5.0 and Opera 11 is working for me. Anyone got a solution for this Problem?

**jQuery Code:**

```
jQuery.fn.center = function(centerCallback) {
    this.css("position", "absolute");
    this.css("top", ($(window).height() - this.height()) / 2 + $(window).scrollTop() + "px");
    this.css("left", ($(window).width() - this.width()) / 2 + $(window).scrollLeft() + "px");
    if (centerCallback != undefined) {
        centerCallback(this);
        return this;
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
    var href = $('#main_navigation a').each(function() {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        if (hash == href.substr(0, href.length - 5)) {
            var toLoad = hash + '.html #content';
            $('#content').load(toLoad)
        }
    });


    $('#main_navigation a').click(function() {
        var toLoad = $(this).attr('href') + ' #content';
        $('#content').hide('fast', loadContent);
        window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0, $(this).attr('href').length - 5);

        function loadContent() {
            $('#content').load(toLoad, '', showNewContent())
        }

        function showNewContent() {
            $('#content').show('normal', hideLoader());
        }

        function hideLoader() {
            $('#load').fadeOut('normal');
        }
        return false;

    });
});


var navi_switch = true;
var content_container = 'test';
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#wrapper').center(function() {
        $('#main_navigation').css("top", (parseInt($('#main_navigation').parent().height()) - parseInt($('#main_navigation').height())) / 2 + "px");
    });

    $('#main_navigation a').click(function() {
        var attr = $(this).attr('href');
        if (navi_switch) {
            $('#main_navigation').animate({
                top: '0'
            }, 500, function() {
                navi_switch = false;
                $('#content').load(attr);
            });
        } else {
            $('#content').load(attr);
        }


        return false;
    });
});
```

Greetings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets see now ...

1. Two click handlers assign to the `a` elements, both making ajax requests to different urls.
2. `$('#content').load(attr);` does not use the `#content` to filter the results..

also

```
function loadContent() {  
    $('#content').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())  
}  
function showNewContent() {  
    $('#content').show('normal',hideLoader());  
}
```

should really be

```
function loadContent() {  
    $('#content').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent /*no parenthesis here, just passing a callback */)  
}  
function showNewContent() {  
    $('#content').show('normal',hideLoader /*no parenthesis here, just passing a callback */);  
}
```

Fix these issues for start, and come back if the issues persist..

---

**Merged Parts**

```
jQuery.fn.center = function(centerCallback) {
    this.css("position", "absolute");
    this.css("top", ($(window).height() - this.height()) / 2 + $(window).scrollTop() + "px");
    this.css("left", ($(window).width() - this.width()) / 2 + $(window).scrollLeft() + "px");
    if (centerCallback != undefined) {
        centerCallback(this);
        return this;
    }
}

var navi_switch = true;
var content_container = 'test';

$(document).ready(function() {

    loadInitialContent(); // call our function to load the initial content based on url hash
    $('#wrapper').center(function() {
        $('#main_navigation').css("top", (parseInt($('#main_navigation').parent().height()) - parseInt($('#main_navigation').height())) / 2 + "px");
    });

    $('#main_navigation a').click(function() {
        var href = $(this).attr('href'); // get the href
        window.location.hash = href.substr(0, href.length - 5); // change the hash of the url
        href += ' #content'; // add the #content filter to the href
        if (navi_switch) {
            $('#main_navigation').animate({
                top: '0'
            }, 500, function() {
                navi_switch = false;
                $('#content').hide('fast', function(){
                   $(this).load(href, function(){
                      $(this).show('normal', function(){
                          $('#load').fadeOut('normal');
                      });
                   });
                });

            });
        } else {
               $('#content').hide('fast', function(){
                   $(this).load(href, function(){
                      $(this).show('normal', function(){
                          $('#load').fadeOut('normal');
                      });
                   });
                });
        }

        return false;
    });
});

function loadInitialContent() {
    var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
    var href = $('#main_navigation a[href^="' + hash + '."]').attr('href') + ' #content';
    $('#content').load(href);
}
```

Comment: Hey Gaby! Thanks for your answer.
I dont really understand what I should do with your second point. I'm kind of new to jQuery and just write this with the jQuery API libary.
What should I change for `$('#content').load(attr);`?
Thanks for your help!

Edit: After i changed the function to your option, the content won't load currently for me. The 'nav' switch up, fall back but now there is no content which loads.

Comment: @Terba, remove the whole first `$(document).ready` block, and in the second one (*that remains*) change `var attr = $(this).attr('href');` to `var attr = $(this).attr('href') + ' #content';`

Comment: Damn! It's working!
Thanks Gaby

There's just two more questions: Is there no way to show the right url? Until now the URL just show http://..../sides/index.html.
That won't change...
The second one is, is there any possibily to animate the content now with a showNewContent function like before? Greetings

Comment: Now I changed my code to the merged Parts and now its now working anymore. The last codechanges with the upper `var attr = $(this).attr('href') + ' #content';` was working perfectly but without animation for the content.

Comment: I try. I guess the "Query" at the start of the merged parts should be "jQUery"?

Comment: Edit: I uploaded it and its now working on [link](http://grener.de/)
Its like you open a .txt file when clicking on an icon. Am I wrong? Thanks for all your help Gaby!

Comment: @Terba, sorry about that.. i missed a few chars and broke the script.. I have update it and should now be ok. (*had a few wrong variable names as well, because i renamed them..*)

Comment: You are my hero for tonight! It's working just like it should. Thanks a lot. I just would like to donate such great help!
Is there any way to get the showNewContent animation to the load or isn't that possible? Greetings

Comment: @Terba, what animation ? I have put the hide/show of the content in the latest update.. do you mean the fadeout to the `#load` element ?

Comment: Ye I know there is the hide / show animation. In my first post up there, I used the showNewContent animation to load the text in. I really like this animation and would ask if its possible to use it in this jQuery, cause I just know about the method with `  $(document).ready(function() {` but not how to use it without. Its no problem if its now working but I would like to use it.

Comment: I just know this solution.
`function loadContent() {
            $('#content').load(toLoad, '', showNewContent())
        }

        function showNewContent() {
            $('#content').show('normal', hideLoader());
        }`  Is it possible to build it in?

Comment: @Terba, check it now.. I have recreated everything you were doing.. Also if you consider this answer to be valid for the question, then you can accept it by clicking the big check icon on the top/left of it..

Comment: Damn, currently you're my god of jQuery.
Check you mails soon if possible, cause I can't tell you how much I love to thank you and I don't get enough reputation to vote you up.
Thanks a LOT Gaby!

Comment: Hey Gaby. It's me again.
I found a little problem: When I use the 'nav'bar to navigate, the content animates just ONCE, not everytime, just the first one. Why? Greetings!

Comment: @Terba, indeed .. i had put the animation code only to the case when the bar was also moving ... code has been updated..